# Command to search where is the config file of apache in Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I use Mint and I often do

```
sudo....
apt-get install xxx
```

It works but later I never know where xxx was installed. I would like to edit-reconfigure my apache 'r root document to use with cakephp but I don't know how.

Comment: Did you configure it at time of install? If so, `dpkg-reconfigure` is your friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
apt-file show apache2
```

As a last resort

```
sudo find / -name httpd.conf
```

Update:

```
  `find / -name httpd | grep "bin.*httpd"` -V | egrep 'ROOT|CONFIG'
```

should produce something like

```
   -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
   -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
   -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Unless you have lots of httpd files in *bin* directories.

Otherwise you can scrutinise the contents of startup scripts such as `/etc/init.d/httpd` or `/etc/init.d/apache*`

Comment: Thanks, but I use command [gedit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf] then I only see [Servername localhost] nothing else in the file.

Comment: Does `/usr/sbin/apachectl -t` say anything?

Comment: No such file or directory!

Comment: Sorry it should be apache2ctl -t which produces SYNTAX OK

Comment: Then `apache2ctl -V` will show you what config file it normally loads (unless a different one is specified in the startup script)